# Getting the Mac to read PDF files aloud

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, text-to-speech

I tried previous suggestion to have my MacBook to read PDFs with speech. I tried Edit -> start speaking in Preview. I also tried the regular way of of using a shortcut key preset in System Preferences for a highlighted section. Nothing happens.

I checked to make sure it reads using other documents and/or screen text.

My eyes need a break and I would like to get speech to read aloud the PDFs. What other suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 6):

Preview voice reading will happen after selecting the text you require to be read first / as mentioned above it needs to be selectable and recognisable text - then proceed with previous steps: Edit -> Speech -> Start Reading

Hope this helps

Comment: How do you speed it up?

Comment: System Preferences ... / Accessibility / Speech.  Change `Speaking Rate` and `System Voice` if want.

Answer (score 3):

A command line solution:

1. Install homebrew. See https://docs.brew.sh/Installation for details.
2. Launch Terminal and run:

   ```
   brew install xpdf
   pdftotext file.pdf - | iconv -t UTF-8//IGNORE | say
   ```

Comment: XPDF command line tools can be installed without brew, FWIW. https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html

Comment: If xpdf is not installed, then an alternative to `xpdf` would be `brew install poppler`. Poppler also installs `pdftotext` utility.

Answer (score 0):

I use Read2Text application, to copy/paste pdf encoded text into it and it reads my files. It's a hassle to copy pages and pages into it, but for now as mac read won't do this, this is what i do, and it does the job.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. If possible, could you edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to also include a link to the Read2Text application you use? This will avoid any ambiguity in the event there are similarly named apps (either now or in future).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the speech > start speaking feature only worked when I selected all the text in the PDF (cmd + A) first.

Answer (score -1):

VoiceOver can only read PDFs that are actually text-encoded. If they are simply image files, it has nothing to "read." You can use Acrobat Pro or another PDF application like [Abbyy FineReader](http://www.abbyy.com/finereader/pro-for-mac/) or [ReadIRIS](http://www.irislink.com/c2-3131-189/Readiris-14-for-Mac---OCR-Software---Scan--convert---manage-documents.aspx) with OCR (Optical Character Recognition) to "read" the graphics and convert them to text. Then you can use VoiceOver to speak if for you. OCR isn't perfect, but it's enough where you'll be able to understand it.